# Upload, View PDF in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

So i was working on a upload, view file for my site but it seems only images and txt files are ready to view, PDF and word documents don't even show. Can someone tell how do i change this so that i can view pdf and word docs in browser?

Here is the upload.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_files(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

And here is the view.php (Updated and working):

```
 <?php
  $file = 'uploads/.pdf';
  $filename = 'yolo.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($file);
?>
```

I only need this to be able to view any PDF without having to have a specific name in the code : `$filename = 'yolo.pdf';`

I have a list of PDF files for the users to see. Is it possible, when clicking the view button, to read the id of the pdf file in the database and to store it in a variable which will be placed in the code? This way php will view the specific file whithout having to change code for every file...

I know this may sound a little confusing so any question just say.

Comment: A warning: your code is not only vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but it's also vulnerable to [HTML Injection/XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection) attacks.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but could you explain? I'm new to this.
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: The two links provided give information about both types of vulnerability. Basically, a user can upload a specially named file that could either generate SQL code you don't want running, or insert HTML you don't want into the page that lists upload files.

Comment: Sorry, just read your comment again and saw the links, my bad. I'll look into it but as my time is a bit short and this is only going to be for show at school and probably never going to be used (or maybe yes we never know), i'm a bit more worried about it working. But don't think i am ignoring your comment it's always good to know a bit more and maybe not for this site but in a later one that will be something i have to look into. Anyway thank you for the warning ;)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to serve the PDF file via PHP script instead of linking it directly?

Comment: No there is none, i just thought since i was using php was supposed to use it here too.

Comment: There is a good reason not to have the PHP interpreter serve files via readfile. Apache/nginx/whatever can do this **MUCH** faster because they don't need to load the PHP interpreter in the first place. Furthermore Apache/nginx/whatever will also handle various caching headers like  `If-Modified-Since` and `ETag`.

Answer (score 1):

First add a numeric auto-incrementing id to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_files` 
    ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ;
```

Then instead of generating a random number with `rand(1000,100000)` use the automatically generated id as a file name. You get this id after the insert with [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

`upload.php`

```
// [snip]

// fetch original file extension
$extension = pathinfo($final_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx"];

// check if the file extension is allowed
if (! in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions))
{
    // report error and abort
}

// use a transaction to rollback the insert 
// in case move_uploaded_file fails
mysql_query("BEGIN");

// insert file into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_files(file,type,size) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($final_file)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($file_type)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($new_size)."')";
mysql_query($sql);

// fetch generated id
$id = mysql_insert_id();

// move file to $folder and rename it to "$id.$extension"
$fileMoved = move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$id.".".$extension);

if ($fileMoved)
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
else
    // deletes file entry from the db
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
```

I took the time to add escaping to your insert in order to prevent sql injection. If you can, you really shouldn't use the old mysql interface anymore and instead switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Serve your files using the id: `view.php?id=1337`

```
<?php
  $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

  if (! $id)
       header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_files WHERE id = ".$id);
  // $id is of type int here, so no sql injection possible

  if (! $result)
       header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

  $file = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  // fetch original file extension or store it the database
  $extension = pathinfo($file["file"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file["file"] . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile("uploads/$id.$extension");
?>
```

If direct access to your files is possible, you should use it for performance reasons:

```
  // [snip]

  // fetch original file extension or store it the database
  $extension = pathinfo($file["file"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  // relocate to the pdf file to have apache/nginx/whatever 
  // serve the file instead of the php interpreter
  header("Location: uploads/$id.$extension");
```

For other readers: If you don't want to grant direct access, but still care about performance, you can use X-Sendfile to serve the files. nginx provides this feature natively. For apache there is a module that sadly doesn't come shipped.

**fix for the final script**

```
    <?php
    include_once 'config_db.php';
    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
    {    

        $allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx"];

        $file = $id."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder="uploads/";

        // new file size in KB
        $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
        // new file size in KB

        // make file name in lower case
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        // make file name in lower case

        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
        $extension = pathinfo($final_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // check if the file extension is allowed
        if (! in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions))
        {
            // report error and abort
            echo "<script>", 
                "alert('invalid file extension');",
                "window.location.href='index.php?fail'",
            "</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ficheiros(file,type,size) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($final_file)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($file_type)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($new_size)."')";

            mysql_query($sql);

            // fetch generated id
            $id = mysql_insert_id();

            // move file to $folder and rename it to "$id.$extension"
            $fileMoved = move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$id.".".$extension);

            if ($fileMoved)
            {
                mysql_query("COMMIT");

                echo "<script>", 
                    "alert('successfully uploaded');",
                    "window.location.href='index.php?success'",
                "</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                // deletes file entry from the db
                mysql_query("ROLLBACK");

                echo "<script>", 
                    "alert('error while uploading file');",
                    "window.location.href='index.php?fail'",
                "</script>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As for the auto increment ID i have one in the table so i'll skip that part. the first code you wrote down should be the upload code where the file is going to be added to the db and the second one should be the view code which will get the id instead of what i had before which only worked for a specific file right?

Comment: Exactly. I skipped parts of your upload script. I hope you see where everything belongs. Otherwise just ask.

Comment: I'll get back to you when i tested this

Comment: The reason why I chose not save files with their original file name: You never know what the user puts into it's filename. `/`, `\ ` and `編` are  possibilities. In the worst case you end up with non-readable file on your disk.

Comment: And since the ID is generated automatically makes more sense to use it since we know that it will always be a readable value. Just one thing. The view code you wrote will be called through a view file link in the page where i list the records. No problem on that right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but (using the 2nd solution with the Location-header) requesting `HTTP GET view.php?id=1337` should behave exactly the same as `HTTP GET uploads/1337.pdf` because the former request will generate a HTTP level relocation to the later. These relocations will be handled automatically by your browser or whatever tool you are using to get the response, like CURL.

Comment: I have a table where i display all the records (files) in the db and in front of each record i have three links (view, download and delete). I can call your view code from the view file link right?

Comment: Yes. :-) To force a download you can instead of `Content-Disposition: inline;...` use `Content-Disposition: attachment; ...`.

Comment: The code is the same just changes the content disposition?

Comment: Yes. It's just an information for the browser what to do with the file. `inline` tells the browser to try and display the file. This works with images, videos, pdfs if supported. `attachment` forces the download dialog. It behaves like you did a right-click and save as ...

Comment: thanks for the explanation. If i make some adjustments would this work for doc (word) and dot (word 97/2003) files?

Comment: I cant imagine that browser are able to display word documents. There is nothing you can do about this from the server side. You could try and convert word documents to pdf or even make images out of them. There are probably some libraries out there but don't expect much in terms of quality. To go the word -> pdf route: I believe you can call open office via shell and tell it to do the conversion. But don't quote me on that. ;-)

Comment: No thats not what i meant, sorry for my short question. I mean upload those files not view them.

Comment: Upload and file shout not be a problem. The move uploaded files functions doesn't care what you upload.

Comment: One point you should think about is the fact that you are currently not restricting what kind of file can be uploaded. You should at least prevent users from uploading *.php files since these would be executed leading to a remote code execution attack. Best practise is to restrict uploads to some known file extensions.

Comment: I updated `upload.php` in my answer. You could also have a list of forbidden extensions and check for those. You would just have to remove the `!` before `in_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? :

```
    <?php
    include_once 'config_db.php';
    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
    {    

        $allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx"];
        $file = $id."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder="uploads/";

        // new file size in KB
        $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
        // new file size in KB

        // make file name in lower case
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        // make file name in lower case

        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
        $extension = pathinfo($final_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ficheiros(file,type,size) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($final_file)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($file_type)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($new_size)."')";
mysql_query($sql);
            mysql_query($sql);
        // fetch generated id
$id = mysql_insert_id();

        // move file to $folder and rename it to "$id.$extension"
$fileMoved = move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$id.".".$extension);

        if ($fileMoved)
            mysql_query("COMMIT");
            <script>
                alert('successfully uploaded');
                window.location.href='index.php?success';
            </script>
        else
        // deletes file entry from the db
            mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Looks good. Two things you need to fix: 1) `$final_file` is defined after you used it for `$extension`. Just move the definition of `$extension` below that of `$final_file`. 2) You mixed up your success and error case, and you have a construct like `if A else B else C` which I'm pretty sure PHP will complain about. Just move C into A, and to fix the mixed up cases switch out A and B to get `if B else A`.

Comment: Yes. The syntax is a bit off, but the interpreter will walk you through the errors. ^^

Comment: Just one question that perhaps you didn't notice. Where do i put the line: if (! in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions))

Comment: I didn't notice some other things as well, like the fact that you call `move_uploaded_file` twice. ;-) I copied your current script to my answer and made some changes. It should now work.

Comment: It gives me an error on the line 6: $allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx"];

Comment: I tried the script you wrote but didn't work. Doesn't show errors but doesn't insertinto db either. I don't know if i fixed it right but i changed line six to: $allowedExtensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx");

Comment: Short array notation is supported only for PHP 5.4.0 and up: https://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Anyway to do it in 3.0? School pc is stupid and bit of a stone age pc so i couldn't put other versions to work --"

Comment: PHP 3 is archaic now. The documentation says that there is no `filter_input`. You have to use `$HTTP_GET_VARS`. Furthermore there is no `pathinfo` so you have to use some string parsing to extract the file extension. There is also no `in_array`and no `isset` so you have to do more work to check the allowed extensions array. Maybe just do a big `if ($ex === "jpg" || "ex === "jpeg" ...`. There also doesn't seem to be `header`. I have no idea how to modifiy the response header without it though. I'd strongly suggest to update to at least php4 or an early php5.

Comment: I managed to update it but i am having errors everywhere due to the use of mysql instead of mysqli. do i just need to write the "i" or is there more to it

Comment: Using mysqli is not that hard. See http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php for a quick start guide. If you need any debugging help with your script, I suggest to open another question with the approriate tags `mysqli`, `php`. You'll get help from the whole community instead of just me here in the comments. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

only view can be done as follows: in a folder must contain php script with following script and a pdf file name abc.pdf

```
<object width="900" height="1125" type="application/pdf" data="abc.pdf?#zoom=100&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content">
    <p>Sorry ur pdf can't be displayed.</p>
  </object>
```